# HTML5 Telephone tag not working on Android Chrome

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

Simple tel link in a tag isn't working on android:

```
<a href="tel:5555555">555555</a>
```

Check it out:
http://jsfiddle.net/4mLCj/1/light/

Is there an easy workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this in Phonegap Application then add the following line in your config.xml file.

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
```